# How to save local data in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a problem of chrome storage.
I set the permission correctly in manifest.json.
I think my code has a problem. (HTML File is fine too. There is only input tag.
Is there someone who can tell me the problem?
Thank you~

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(function (data) {
    var input = document.querySelector('input');
    if(data.count == 1){
        input.value = data.getData;
    }
});



var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var input = document.querySelector('input');
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
        input.value = tab.url;
        var getData = input.value;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            'getData' : getData,
            'count' : 1
        });
    });
});
```

If, I click the btn, I want to get the url data in input=text form.
However, before clicking btn, there is already url data in input.
The thing that I want to do is 
1. click btn and it saves url in input form.
2. If I delete the data in input form, it remains data like I did. 
(I mean input form maintains empty data if I delete the value.)

Conclusion : click! get data locally! 
If you don't understand my question, please comment.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: _"I know I can use Chrome's storage, but it's really hard to understand, and it gives me errors."_ You really should show your efforts so that we can find what's wrong with your understanding. As-is, the question is generic "write code for me since I can't", which is not a good fit.

Comment: I'm really sorry to make you upset.
It's my first question so I didn't know what is a good question.
Sorry again. 
I will show you the result and please see what's wrong.

Comment: No, I don't think I understand what the problem is now. You say that: _"However, before clicking btn, there is already url data in input."_ - that's indeed what your code is supposed to do. What isn't working as you want then?